# Реализация большого выпадающего меню с несколькими уровнями вложенности

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

Коллеги, необходима ваша помощь - нужно реализовать большое выпадающее меню с 3 уровнями вложенности. Моих мозгов на данный момент не хватает чтобы продумать логику и последовательность.
По ссылке сверстанный мини пример - https://codepen.io/proququ/pen/eYNvmGq

Изначально меню выглядит следующим образом:
[image: изначальный вид]

После клика по бургеру:
[image: раскрывшееся меню]

Т.е. по клику раскрывается шапка, верхнее меню перемещается в левую часть и перестраивается и мы видим три уровня меню, первый пункт выделен автоматически, соответственно первый подпункт тоже.
При клике на другие основные пункты меню, ранее выбранные скрываются и выезжают дочерние.
Я уже всю голову сломал, просто ховер здесь не подходит, знаний джса у меня не хватает, подумал что наверно более менее подходящяя идея, это по клику на бургер вырезать каждый уровень и поместить в одну из трех колонок, но не могу связать и анимировать клик и выезжание нужного подменю и... как вернуть меню снова вверх тоже не понимаю.

```js
$('.burger').click(function(){

 $(this).toggleClass(' active');
 $(this).parents('.container').toggleClass(' drop-menu');
 $('.menu').detach().prependTo('.big-nav__col--1');
 $('.submenu').detach().prependTo('.big-nav__col--2');
 $('.subsubmenu').detach().prependTo('.big-nav__col--3');
 $('.bottom-row').slideToggle(350);
 
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
.upper-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu__list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.submenu,
.subsubmenu{
  display: none;
}
.bottom-row {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.big-nav {
  display: flex;
}
.big-nav__col {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.big-nav .menu__list {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.big-nav .menu__list a {
  padding: 10px;
}
.big-nav .menu__list a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
.big-nav .submenu,
.big-nav .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0 15px;
}
.info p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="upper-row">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu__list">
        <li>
         <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
         <div class="submenu">
           <ul class="submenu__list">
             <li>
               <a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a>
               <div class="subsubmenu">
                 <ul class="subsubmenu__list">
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
         <div class="submenu">
           <ul class="submenu__list">
             <li>
               <a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a>
               <div class="subsubmenu">
                 <ul class="subsubmenu__list">
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3 уровня</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2 уровня</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Пункт 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="burger">Меню</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-row">
    <div class="big-nav">
      <div class="big-nav__col big-nav__col--1"></div>
      <div class="big-nav__col big-nav__col--2">
        при клике на основной пункт меню, в эту колонку слева выезжает подменю
      </div>
      <div class="big-nav__col big-nav__col--3">
        при клике на пункт подменю, в эту колонку слева выезжает 3 уровень
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Телефон компании</p>
      <p>Адрес компании</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Идея в том, что все находящееся в выпадающем меню - это обычные табы, которые переключается между собой и внутри себя. Думаю, верхние элементы меню в навигации не должны никуда перестраиваться, они просто исчезают на момент раскрытия меню и появляются когда мы снова закрываем его. Стили использовать по своему усмотрению.

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
const burger = document.querySelector('.nav-burger');

const burgerHandler = () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
}
burger.addEventListener('click', burgerHandler);

const Tabs = (element, props) => {
  const node = element;
  let selectors = null;
  let tabIndex = {
    prev: 0,
    next: 0
  };

  const requestSelectors = () => {
    return selectors = {
      tabsNavigationParent: node.querySelector('.tabs-navigation'),
      tabsNavigationItems: [...node.querySelector('.tabs-navigation').children],
      tabsContentParent: node.querySelector('.tabs-content'),
      tabsContentItems: [...node.querySelector('.tabs-content').children]
    }
  }

  const toggleContent = () => {
    const {
      tabsNavigationItems,
      tabsContentItems
    } = selectors;
    tabsContentItems[tabIndex.prev].classList.remove('active');
    tabsNavigationItems[tabIndex.prev].classList.remove('active');
    tabsContentItems[tabIndex.next].classList.add('active');
    tabsNavigationItems[tabIndex.next].classList.add('active');
  }

  const requestActiveNodes = (index) => {
    tabIndex.prev = tabIndex.next;
    tabIndex.next = index;
    if (tabIndex.prev === tabIndex.next) return;
    toggleContent();
  }

  const init = () => {
    const {
      tabsNavigationItems,
      tabsContentItems
    } = selectors;
    tabsContentItems[tabIndex.next].classList.add('active');
    tabsNavigationItems[tabIndex.next].classList.add('active');

    tabsNavigationItems.forEach((label, i) => {
      label.addEventListener('click', () => {
        requestActiveNodes(i)
      })
    })
  }

  if (node) {
    requestSelectors();
    init();
  }
}

const tabs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-widget="tabs"]')];
tabs.forEach(x => {
  Tabs(x);
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.nav {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 50px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.active .nav-items {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-burger {
  width: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-burger:before,
.nav-burger:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: .5rem 0;
}

.nav-burger span {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translatex(20%);
  transform: translatex(20%);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.active .nav-burger span {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
  transform: translatex(0);
}

.nav-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-100%);
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  padding: 10rem 5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-menu .item {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.active .nav-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
  transform: translatey(0);
}

.tabs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.tabs-navigation>* {
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-navigation>*.active {
  color: #82c751;
}

.tabs-content>* {
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation: show .3s;
  animation: show .3s;
}

.tabs-content>*.active {
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-logo"></div>
  <div class="nav-items">
    <div class="item">Оборудование</div>
    <div class="item">Сервисные услуги</div>
    <div class="item">Оснастка и аксессуары</div>
    <div class="item">Полезные инструменты</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-burger"><span></span></div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tabs" data-widget="tabs">
        <div class="tabs-navigation">
          <div class="item active">Оборудование</div>
          <div class="item">Сервисные услуги</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-content">
          <div class="item">
            <div data-widget="tabs" class="tabs">
              <div class="tabs-navigation">
                <div class="item">
                  #1 Оборудование
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  #2 Оборудование
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tabs-content">
                <div class="item">
                  <p>#1-1 Оборудование</p>
                  <p>#1-2 Оборудование</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <p>#2-1 Оборудование</p>
                  <p>#2-1 Оборудование</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div data-widget="tabs" class="tabs">
              <div class="tabs-navigation">
                <div class="item">
                  #1 Сервисные услуги
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  #2 Сервисные услуги
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tabs-content">
                <div class="item">
                  <p>#1-1 Сервисные услуги</p>
                  <p>#1-2 Сервисные услуги</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <p>#2-1 Сервисные услуги</p>
                  <p>#2-2 Сервисные услуги</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик, буду разбираться.
Перестраивание связано с тем, что меню выводится пхп функцией и при Вашем варианте получится, что в шапке мы имеет два громоздких блока многоуровневого меню (в плане хтмл кода). Вероятно об этом надо было написать заранее, поэтому прошу прощения.